# Switching to Codeigniter HMVC - Undefined functions?

Tags: function, codeigniter, undefined, hmvc

I have setup a fresh install of codeigniter 2x and modular extensions (https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home)

It is my first time using HMVC, the decision to move from MVC to HMVC was to give myself more control of my login, admin, and members areas.

I have created my first controller in HMVC like so....

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends MX_Controller {


    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();  
        $this->load->model('Content_model');
    }


    public function index()
    {

        $this->load->view('includes/template'); 
    }
}
```

and a view like:

```
<?php echo doctype(); ?>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title><?php echo $pagecontent['seo_title']; ?></title>
         <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $pagecontent['seo_description']; ?>" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $pagecontent['seo_keywords']; ?>" />
        <meta name='robots' content='all' />

        <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="<?php echo base_url("images/favicon.png"); ?>" />
        <?php echo link_tag('css/style.css'); ?>
 <script type="text/javascript"  language="javascipt" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("js/jquery.validate.min.js"); ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("js/main.js"); ?>"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <?php $this->load->view('includes/notify'); ?>

        <div id="topbar">
            <?php $this->load->view('includes/topbar'); ?>
```

When I try and view the page in my browser I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function doctype() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mintfifty\application\modules\site\views\includes\template.php on line 1
```

The code has worked in all my previous codeigniter (mvc) projects but not (hmvc) why is it not working in HMVC? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is not likely to be caused by HMVC. `doctype()` function is defined in `html` helper and it seems that You have not loaded it (Unless you have auto-loaded it). Just load the html helper in your controller and it should work fine.

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('html');
    $this->load->view('includes/template'); 
}
```